# How to manipulate numeric values of some html tags and return new value instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, calculation

im new to js and im trying to manipulate values of some h4 and some other tags then do some little math on each and return the new value back to the tag.
thanks to @drydenlong & @oliverong i was able to achieve this so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Discount</span>
        <input class="discount" type="text" placeholder="eg 30.22">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="product">
         <h2>Product 1</h2>
         <h4 class="maththis">100</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="product">
         <h2>Product 2</h2>
         <h4 class="maththis">200</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="product">
         <h2>Product 3</h2>
         <h4 class="maththis" id="total">300</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this basic js

```
$('.discount').on('input',function(){
  var base = parseInt($('.maththis').html());
  var dis = $('.discount').val();
  var newsum = dis - base;  
  $('.maththis').text(newsum);
});
```

i ran into some troubles and got stucked now :(

1) the calculation happens on keydown and that changes the values instantly, so there is also no going back. no new calculation possible unless relaoding page.

2) since im trying to change more values at once i also need to handle global variables i guess because in this example the value of text(). adds just the strings of the variable maththis toghether instead of each. so it makes 100 + 200 + 300= 100200300. this miscalculation gives also a NaN back.

how can i fix it so that the calculation happens on each class="maththis" seperatly and not together and how can i fix the value problem of class="maththis", so that i keep the original value somewhere incase i need to make changes on the discount value?

PEN: https://codepen.io/vup/pen/RxKjrw
PEN click function: https://codepen.io/vup/pen/Qadaqz

thanks alot <3

Comment: What is your attempt? Start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: `val()` is for  form controls like `<input>`, `<select>` etc

Comment: To get the value of `maththis` try the jQuery `html()`. You also need also need to convert the value to integer cause `html()` returns a string, you can do this by using `parseInt()`. So it would look something like this `var newVal = parseInt($('.maththis').html())` then pass it back by just this `$('.maththis').html(newVal)`.

Comment: i tried on some pens so far but couldnt figure out :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` will get you what is inside of the `h1` element, so something like this will return 100:

```
var h1Val = $(".maththis").text();
```

Then you can use `val()` on whatever input field you have to do the math. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
var discount = $(".discount").val();
var h1Val = $(".maththis").text();
var total = h1Val - discount;
//Do whatever you need with the result
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$('.discount').on('input',function(){
    var base = $('.maththis').text();
    var dis = $('.discount').val();
    var total = base - dis;
    $('#total').text('Total: '+total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="discount" type="text" />
<h1 class="maththis">100</h1>

<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: wow, awesome respons time! thank you very much dryden! could you maybe help me out with a pen or fiddle? my next problem would be to change the original value of the h1 tag and doind it without a "do calc" button :-/

Comment: The code I provided should be enough to get you there. I'm already changing the contents of one element, try changing it to another. Also, try looking up the different functions used in my code to see what they do, you'll learn a lot more doing that way instead of just having the code given to you

Comment: thank you very much dryden and all others too! im so surprised about the response time here. very nice! sorry for my weired way to describe the problem. your code works like charm thanks! my problem is the returning value, the manipulation of the original value. what im trying to achive is this "  $('.maththis').text('Total: '+total);"  but since its on the fly, it always calculates, so after typing in 2 digits i get NaN back.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
let num = +document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText
```

In jquery:

```
let num = +$('h1').text();
```